# openoffice calc python function does not modify sheet

Tags: python, excel

I have defined a function hellotest defined below to be executed under OpenOffice calc.
This function simply writes Hello word in the cell(3,4).
The sheet is modified when the function is executed as a macro but nothing happens when the function is executed via a basic function named HELLOTEST (see below).
It seems that the python function is called as the string "Hello world" that it returns is displayed in the calling cell but the cell(3,4) is not modified.
Should I understand that the python function can only be executed as a macro or should I use XSCRIPTCONTEXT in a different way ?

Python:

```
import uno

def hellotest():
   oSheet = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument().getSheets().getByIndex(0)
   oCell1 = oSheet.getCellByPosition(3,4) 
   oCell1.setString("Hello world")
   return "Hello world"
```

Basic function:

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****
REM Keep a global reference to the ScriptProvider, since this stuff may be     called many times:
Global g_MasterScriptProvider

REM Specify location of Python script providing the cell functions:
Const URL_Main = "vnd.sun.star.script:hellotest.py$"
Const URL_Args = "?language=Python&location=user"

Function getMasterScriptProvider()
   if NOT isObject(g_MasterScriptProvider) then
      oMasterScriptProviderFactory =     createUnoService("com.sun.star.script.provider.MasterScriptProviderFactory")
      g_MasterScriptProvider = oMasterScriptProviderFactory.createScriptProvider("")
   endif
   getMasterScriptProvider = g_MasterScriptProvider
End Function

Function HELLOTEST(s$, optional iLen%)
   sURL = URL_Main & "hellotest" & URL_Args
   oMSP = getMasterScriptProvider()
   oScript = oMSP.getScript(sURL)
   x = oScript.invoke(Array(),Array(),Array())
   HELLOTEST = x
End Function`
```